# Strong vs bold, italic vs emphasis: the html5 match

Tags: html, semantic-markup

what I've understood after some lurking, is:

`<b>` should be used for markup text without semantic importance, `<strong>` for strong semantic importance

`<i>` should be used for language change (in any form), `<em>` for `<em>some damned stress emphasis!!!!</em>` (not a language change but something that you will pronounce with more emphasis)

is this correct? can you write please some examples, in simple english?!

thank you in advance

Comment: It's not way off, but not very correct either. I encourage you to [read the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#text-level-semantics). It comes with descriptions of various cases, and a number of good examples to help you along.

Comment: Here are direct links to sections for [`em`](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-em-element) vs [`i`](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element), and [`strong`](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) vs [`b`](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) at whatwg.org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your examples are basically right, although many would argue your `<B>` and `<I>` markup should be done in CSS.  Voiceover software, braille readers, and other accessibility tools won't mention to a disabled person about bold text, but they will communicate emphasis.